# Alert view method is not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, uialertview

In my app i have reset button which delete all the data of tables and database.but before deleting i have to put alert view and ask the question as follows:

```
- (IBAction)resetData:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bills Data Entry"
                      message:@"Are you sure want to reset data?" delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        [self databaseOpen];
        NSString *deleteData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from tbl_Bills"];
        [database executeQuery:deleteData];
        NSLog(@"inert query: %@",deleteData);
        NSLog(@"records deleted");
        [table reloadData];
        [database close];

        // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

This method is not called when i click on yes.

Comment: Did you use breakpoints to make sure that the program enters the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIAlertView's delegate must not be nil if you want to invoke its delegate method.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bills Data Entry"
                        message:@"Are you sure want to reset data?" delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
```

Comment: Ya correct he has set the delegate to nil,then how would he be able to hit the delegate method...cheers

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertView delegate must be set to self if you want to invoke its delegate method.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bills Data Entry"
                                          message:@"Are you sure want to reset data?"
                                          delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  When you are using Delegate method you are supposed to set "delegate: self" instead of nil.

  UIAlertView *my_Alert = [[UIAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title of Alert" message:@"Your 
                          Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK", 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
```